# Getting a 403 forbidden while deploying to tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7, gradle

I have a gradle based project and I'm using cargo to deploy war to tomcat7. In another project which is maven based, I'm perfectly able to deploy. I'm running these projects on my mac. The only difference is in maven project, this is configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <warFile>${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
    <server>TomcatServer</server>
    <path>/mypath</path>
</configuration>
```

But in gradle, cargo deploys to localhost:8080/manager/text and I think that's why I'm getting a 403. The same build file runs perfectly fine on my ubuntu.

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'cargo'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = 'GitHub'
            addArtifactPattern 'http://cloud.github.com/downloads/[organisation]/[module]/[module]-[revision].[ext]'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:0.3'
    }
}

cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat7x'
    port = 8080
    context = 'mypath'
    remote {
        hostname = 'localhost'
        username = 'username'
        password = 'passwd'
    }
}

dependencies {
    cargo 'org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-uberjar:1.1.1',
          'org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-ant:1.1.1',
          'jaxen:jaxen:1.1.1'
}
```

In my tomcat-users.xml, I have included manager, manager-script and manager-gui roles. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: The plugin version you use is over 2 years old. You should probably upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko As you said, I have upgraded to org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:0.6.1 but I get the same error. Basically this plugin is trying to fetch /manager/text/list but this url is not valid. I get : {GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1: null}. And because of this, I'm getting a org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException hence deploy failed. How do I enable deploying to /manager/text on tomcat?

Comment: I fixed the issue. I had changed to use tomcat 6 and thats why I was getting 403